# How to use 'sort by date' via javaScript in table data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function

I have used a JavaScript code that comes with my web template. but I want to sort my table by date by default.

I am attaching a screenshot of my result and marking what I really want.

[image]

```js
<!-- Script for sort, pagination and search on table -->
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#datatables').DataTable({
   "pagingType": "full_numbers",
   "lengthMenu": [
  [25, 50, 100, -1],
  [25, 50, 100, "All"]
   ],
   responsive: true,
   language: {
  search: "_INPUT_",
  searchPlaceholder: "Search records",
   }
 });

 var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();

 // Edit record
 table.on('click', '.edit', function() {
   $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
   var data = table.row($tr).data();
   alert('You press on Row: ' + data[0] + ' ' + data[1] + ' ' + data[2] + '\'s row.');
 });

 // Delete a record
 table.on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
   $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
   table.row($tr).remove().draw();
   e.preventDefault();
 });

 //Like record
 table.on('click', '.like', function() {
   alert('You clicked on Like button');
 });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();
```

After this line add the below line

```
table.fnSort( [ [2,'asc'] ] );
```

Comment: Thanks, Brindha Baskaran but this not worked for me.